# WooCommerce: get_current_screen not working with multi language

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual

I am developing a WooCommerce plugin and I am using `get_current_screen` to identify the current screen slug to load css and js.

But when using [**WooCommerce Branding plugin**](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-branding/) or any other language than English, the slug changes.

Eg : default slug will be like `woocommerce-settings`. 
If using branding, then it changes like this `wp-dev-settings`.

I just wanted to know how I can identify the current screen slug ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try WordPress global variable  in some contexts `global $pagename;`

or

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
?>
```

Comment: No this cant be used. it just returns the current file like admin.php or something i need the exact screen slug like woocommerce-settings-page

Comment: Try post_name variable then. Everything in WP is based on post

Comment: Yes i know but the thing is.. i mainly work on admin side. and in admin side not all are post. i do have a custom page..

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the current screen slug from the 'parent' attribute of the screen object. For example, if my shop name via WC Branding plugin is "Vishals Shop", then:

`[base] => vishals-shop_page_wc-settings
[parent_base] => woocommerce`

Now you can replace the shop name with the parent_base & get the real slug name of that page.